# How can I wait for a variable to initialize before running a function? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I call the function from useEffect() using a variable that receives data from the extension in the browser. But function called before init a value. How can I wait for a variable to initialize? And then call function... I need to get `valueFromExtention` and then call `doSomething()`

```
const myFunction = () => {
 const valueFromExtention = window.objectFromExtension.someProp;
 doSomething(valueFromExtention);
}

UseEffect(() => {
  myFunction();
}, [])
```

Comment: can u show us what have u tried

Answer (score 0):

Just write conditional logic that checks for a value.

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        if(typeof value !== "undefined"){
         //code
        }                   
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
const myFunction = (value) => doSomething(value);

UseEffect(() => {
  const valueFromExtention = window.objectFromExtension.someProp;
  if(valueFromExtention)
      myFunction(valueFromExtention);
}, [])
```

Comment: `valueFromExtention` init after 1-7 second. But I need to call `myFunction()` necessary

Comment: does the extension fire an event when the value is avaible?

Comment: whats the name of the extension you are using?

Comment: TronLink wallet